# Node.js - EJS - including a partial

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to use Embedded Javascript renderer for node: 
https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs

I would like to know how I can include another view file (partial) inside a .ejs view file.

Comment: The partial system is actually a part of ExpressJS, I believe.  Are you using the Express framework?

Comment: No, I am not using that.. I probably have to go down that route if it's not possible with just a templating engine.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

With Express 3.0:

```
<%- include myview.ejs %>
```

the path is relative from the caller who includes the file, not from the views directory set with `app.set("views", "path/to/views")`.

[EJS v1 includes](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs#includes)
[EJS v2 includes](https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes)

(Update: the newest syntax for ejs v3.0.1 is `<%- include('myview.ejs') %>`)

Comment: this should be the correct answer since the developer of ejs / express updated the code.

Comment: In ejs2 I hade code like that looked like this and worked.
<% include myview.ejs %>
In ejs3 it need to look like this
<%- include('myview.ejs') %>
Guess the number of hours it took for me to realise I had to add the dash in the beginning?
(Just adding this comment in case someone else in the same situation reads it.)

Comment: `<%- include('partials/footer') %>` works as well

Comment: The correct link now should be: https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes

Answer (score 25):

> **Works with Express 4.x :**

The Correct way to include partials in the template according to [this](https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes) you should use:

`<%- include('partials/youFileName.ejs') %>`.

You are using:

`<% include partials/yourFileName.ejs %>`

which is deprecated.

Answer (score 21):

In Express `4.x` I used the following to load `ejs`:

```
  var path = require('path');

  // Set the default templating engine to ejs
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

  // The views/index.ejs exists in the app directory
  app.get('/hello', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'title'});
  });
```

Then you just need two files to make it work - `views/index.ejs`:

```
<%- include partials/navigation.ejs %>
```

And the `views/partials/navigation.ejs`:

```
<ul><li class="active">...</li>...</ul>
```

---

You can also tell Express to use `ejs` for html templates:

```
var path = require('path');
var EJS  = require('ejs');

app.engine('html', EJS.renderFile);

// Set the default templating engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// The views/index.html exists in the app directory
app.get('/hello', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index.html', {title: 'title'});
});
```

---

Finally you can also use the `ejs` layout module:

```
var EJSLayout = require('express-ejs-layouts');
app.use(EJSLayout);
```

This will use the `views/layout.ejs` as your layout.

Comment: i got missing ) error, i have to put it like <%- include ('partials/navbar.ejs') %>

Answer (score 10):

**As of Express 4.x**

**app.js**

```
// above is all your node requires

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); <-- ./views has all your .ejs files
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

**error.ejs**

```
<!-- because ejs knows your root directory for views, you can navigate to the ./base directory and select the header.ejs file and include it -->

<% include ./base/header %> 
<h1> Other mark up here </h1>
<% include ./base/footer %>
```

Answer (score 4):

**app.js** add

```
app.set('view engine','ejs')
```

add your partial file(ejs) in views/partials

in **index.ejs**

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs') %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Express 3.x no longer support partial. According to the post [ejs 'partial is not defined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351691/ejs-partial-is-not-defined), you can use "include" keyword in EJS to replace the removed partial functionality.

Comment: Check out ejs-locals for expresss 3 support.

Answer (score 2):

In oficial documentation https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes show that includes works like that:

```
<%- include('../partials/head') %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Also

```js
<%- include('partials/header.ejs',{paramName: paramValue}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <form method="post" class="mt-3">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="plantName" name="plantName" placeholder="plantName">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="price" name="price" placeholder="price">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="harvestTime" name="harvestTime" placeholder="time to harvest">
          </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-md-4">Submit</button>
      </form>

<form method="post">
        <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">FarmName</th>
                <th scope="col">Player Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Birthday Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Money</th>
                <th scope="col">Day Played</th>
                <th scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <%for (let i = 0; i < farms.length; i++) {%>
                 <tr>
                    <td><%= farms[i]['id'] %></td>
                    <td><%= farms[i]['farmName'] %></td>
                    <td><%= farms[i]['playerName'] %></td>
                    <td><%= farms[i]['birthDayDate'] %></td>
                    <td><%= farms[i]['money'] %></td>
                    <td><%= farms[i]['dayPlayed'] %></td>
                    <td><a href="<%=`/farms/${farms[i]['id']}`%>">Look at Farm</a></td>
                </tr>
            <%}%>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Enividu Indonesia. Please, consider adding more details on your answer instead of only the code.

Answer (score 0):

For including ejs file you must use:

```
<%- include("file-name") %>
```

Note: NO need to use `.ejs` in file name.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to Worry It's Very Simple
Only Follow the Below Step

1. **<%- include("partials/header") -%>**  //for header.ejs
2. This EJS Body Content
3. <%=abt%>
4. **<%-include("partials/footer") -%>**   //for footer.ejs

Answer (score 0):

// app.ejs

- `<%- include('header'); -%>` //for file header.ejs
- `<%- include('footer'); -%>` // for file footer.ejs
- `app.post("/", function(req, res) { res.render("header") });`
- `app.post("/", function(req, res) { res.render("footer") });`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

For including **ejs** file you must use:

`<%- include("relative path of ejs ") -%>`

Answer (score -4):

EJS by itself currently does not allow view partials. Express does.

Comment: Outdated info. New version supports it as per comment by @pkyeck