# How to include html code in a view?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using **express.js** and **EJS** as template engine.
I don't understand how to use partials, I have seen at the examples but the author used JADE template engine, so I don't know how to apply it with EJS.

I have a simple view named: test.ejs and another .ejs file named part1.ejs

I need to show part1.ejs inside test.ejs.

I tried putting `<% partial('part1', {}) %>` (into test.ejs) but nothing happen, It does not include that file.

Could someone give me an example?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct code in your situation would be:

```
<%- partial('part1') %>
```

If you want to include unescaped HTML use `<%-` and if you want to escape HTML (unlinkely though when including a partial) you can use `<%=`.

Resources:

[Node.js - EJS - including a partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404830/node-js-ejs-including-a-partial) 
http://groups.google.com/group/express-js/browse_thread/thread/62d02af36c83b1cf

Answer (score 4):

Its an old thread, but here is how you do it in the newer version of EJS.

```
<% include part1 %>
```

given `part1.ejs` contains the html you wish to include.