# function in ejs: how to return html

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have a function from which i d like to return a small html snippet.

in the page.ejs
    
            <% for(var i=0; i < studentList.length; i++) { %>

```
                <td> <%= rateStudent(studentList[i].metricArray)%> </td>

            </tr>
        <% } %>
</tbody>
```

somewhere in the page.js

```
function rateStudent(metricArray){
     // omitted

        return '<span class="label label-danger"> Zayif </span>';
    };
```

the function is called, everything works. But the function returns the snippet  and i see it printed as text :) is it normal?

how can i return a div snippet from a ejs function?

```
<span class="label label-danger"> Zayif </span>
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include html code in a view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547131/how-to-include-html-code-in-a-view)

Comment: I believe you can make the HTML safe by changing the way ejs prints: `<%- rateStudent(studentList[i].metricArray)%>`. Note the dash instead of the equals in the opening EJS tag

Comment: magic. that was it @Brennan thanks!