# My EJS include causes error in my express app.

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to make my site more component based using includes in my application but it just throws an error to the page when I reload it. I have tried:

```
<%=include _partials/site-head/site-head %>
```

And I have tried:

```
<%=include virtual="_partials/site-head/site-head" %>
```

Here is the code.

```
<%=include virtual="_partials/site-head/site-head" %>

    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <% for(var i=0; i<userlist.length; i++) {%>
       <p><%= userlist[i].name %></p>
    <% } %>

<%=include virtual="_partials/site-foot/site-foot" %>
```

Comment: What is outputted in error?

Comment: It just redirects me to my error ejs page.

Comment: Try <%- include _partials/site-head/site-head.ejs %>

Comment: Nope that didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

Tag <%= is used to output variables, for code need to use <%- %>. So to include views you need to write like this:

```
<%- include _partials/site-head/site-head.ejs %>

    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <% for(var i=0; i<userlist.length; i++) {%>
       <p><%= userlist[i].name %></p>
    <% } %>

<%- include _partials/site-head/site-foot.ejs %>
```

Also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404830/node-js-ejs-including-a-partial).

Answer (score 0):

My Answer that solved this was to check what version of express your using, I was using an old version which didnt like include.