# More simple inclusion in EJS, avoiding nested file context

Tags: node.js, templates, ejs

So kind of building off of [Node.js - EJS - including a partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404830/node-js-ejs-including-a-partial)

I’ve got a series of EJS templates, all organized in a series of folder. Many include the same `header.ejs` file. For each include, I need to have an include along the lines of `<% include ../partials/footers/footer %>`. Because some files are nested deeper/in more folders than others, each has to be set manually.

Is there a solution to avoid this? For example, is there a parameter to set all `include`s to be based from the root of the `views` directory (in which all `.ejs` files are placed)?