# Issue with partials using EJS in express

Tags: node.js, express, pug, ejs, templating

Just to preface: I've recently been transitioning my web development skills from PHP + HTML/CSS to Nodejs, but have been having trouble with templating.

I'm using Express, and after some research tried to use [Pug.js](http://pugjs.org), but found that too complicated for what I'm trying to achieve at the moment, so I moved to ejs as it seemed to be more simple.

What I'm trying to get is to be able to reuse HTML that I have already written for multiple pages on the site - which from what I've found is called 'partials'?

Now to the code I've written so far:

*server.js:*

```
var express = require('express');
app = express();
publicFolder = __dirname + '/public';

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(publicFolder, {
    extensions: ['html']
}));

app.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('Server is online on port 80')
});
```

*index.html:* (/public/index.html)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <% include ../views/header.ejs %>
    </body>
</html>
```

*header.ejs:* (/views/header.ejs)

```
<h1>Test header</h1>
```

I understand I may be on the completely wrong track, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

EDIT: I've double checked to make sure it's not a path issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js - EJS - including a partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404830/node-js-ejs-including-a-partial)

Comment: use `<%- xxx%>` instead of `<%  xxx %>`

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately @JerryChen

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier for you to store all your view files as `ejs` in the same folder and user the `path` `module` to set your static files.

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path')
app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('Server is online on port 80')
});
```

index.ejs

```
<html>
    <body>
        <% include header %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just a consideration. Hope it helps!