# how to include an ejs file in another ejs file?

Tags: node.js

I can't include `footer.ejs` inside `home.ejs`

**app.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs")

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home')
});
```

**view/home.ejs**:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>

<% include partials/footer.ejs %>
```

**view/partials/footer.ejs**

```
<p>End</p>
```

this is the error I get when i try to reach `home`:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in /home/ubuntu/Documents/moreExpress/EJSdemo/views/home.ejs while compiling ejs
>
> > If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
> >     https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
> >     Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
> >         at new Function ()
> >         at Template.compile (/home/ubuntu/Documents/moreExpress/EJSdemo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:626:12)
> >         at Object.compile (/home/ubuntu/Documents/moreExpress/EJSdemo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:366:16)
> >         at handleCache (/home/ubuntu/Documents/moreExpress/EJSdemo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:215:18)
> >         at tryHandleCache (/home/ubuntu/Documents/moreExpress/EJSdemo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:254:16)
> >         at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/ubuntu/Documents/moreExpress/EJSdemo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:459:10)
> >         at View.render (/home/ubuntu/Documents/moreExpress/EJSdemo/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
> >         at tryRender (/home/ubuntu/Documents/moreExpress/EJSdemo/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
> >         at Function.render (/home/ubuntu/Documents/moreExpress/EJSdemo/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
> >         at ServerResponse.render (/home/ubuntu/Documents/moreExpress/EJSdemo/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - EJS - including a partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404830/node-js-ejs-including-a-partial)