# In nodejs, how can I use '_dirname' in ejs file type?

Tags: node.js, ejs, dirname

I am trying to display an image in an EJS file and managed to get the file name, however, I would need the relative path, i.e. `__dirname + filename` to display that image.

Answer (score 0):

Manage to access the folder using the absolute path, i.e. from the root directory:

```
("../uploadImages/" + product[i].productImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `path.join()` for better accessibility:

```
const path = require("path");
// rest of code
const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, "uploadImages/" + product[i].productImage);
```

Comment: thanks Ayman, sorry for being thick, what would I include in path.js? I presume "__dirname"?

Comment: I presumed you used Node.JS along with EJS. My answer was a result of that.If you want to know more about using node and EJS, you can refer to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404830/node-js-ejs-including-a-partial